# HTML Download=True not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, download

I have the following, generated from Ruby, but the the HTML in the view-source is:

```
 <a download="true" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/....blah blah" target="_blank">
                        <span class='download_link_text col-xs-10'>
                          All Grantee Comments and Suggestions
                        </span>
                        </a>
```

I believe that the `download="true"` SHOULD make it automatically download the file into downloads. What it seems to do pull the file up int a new tab. (It's possible it's not even doing that, testing this realistically is becoming hard).

Am I understanding the `download="true"` correctly? is it being used incorrectly?  Is there some other common error that would cause this behavior?

Ruby/Rails/HAML included below just in case it's relevant:

```
 = link_to download_material.url_content, download: true, target: "_blank" do
    %i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-o-down.download_circle_arrow.col-xs-2
    %span.download_link_text.col-xs-10
      = download_material.title
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is correct.
But, this attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

You can check more about that here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download
- https://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: Interesting. Is this new? hmmm, or perhaps historically, we gave our domain name to the S3 links...

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe because of security, there are issues reported at Chrome (1y ago) and Firefox (5y ago)

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714373 -
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874009 -

Use `href` with `target="_blank`, may it will be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You put the URL in the `download` attribute

```html
<a download="https://s3.amazonaws.com/....blah blah" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/....blah blah" target="_blank">
    <span class='download_link_text col-xs-10'>
        All Grantee Comments and Suggestions
    </span>
</a>
```

Technically the `href` attribute doesn't matter but it is a good reference to see what you are downloading.

**Edit:** I actually looked at W3schools documentation and it said if you have the `href` attribute, then you don't need to put anything in the `download` attribute. The value in the `download` attribute can be useful when you want the user to download a different file than the one included in the href attribute.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp